# Creating acceleration of an object (tank) in a game

Tags: c++, game-physics

I'm having a trouble with making my Tank accelerate when I press a move button and decelerate when I let go of it. Don't be too harsh on me for not being a pro because I'm still learnig and Thanks in advance!

I also have variables called 'speed' and 'maxspeed' which I played around with and it didn't turn out to well, and the code below basicaly makes my tank move in an update function

```
if(TestName->Tank[0].up == true){
            TestName->Tank[0].position_y = TestName->Tank[0].position_y + (TestName->Tank[0].speed +     0.06f);
        }
        if(TestName->Tank[0].down == true){
            TestName->Tank[0].position_y = TestName->Tank[0].position_y - 0.06f;
        }
        if(TestName->Tank[0].right == true){
            TestName->Tank[0].rotation = TestName->Tank[0].rotation + 0.6f;
        }
        if(TestName->Tank[0].left == true){
            TestName->Tank[0].rotation = TestName->Tank[0].rotation - 0.6f;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: i dont know how to make my tank accelerate over time instead of having constant speed at all times

Comment: a=dv/dt, i.e. acceleration is the change of velocity over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this bit of code:

```
TestName->Tank[0].position_y = TestName->Tank[0].position_y + (TestName->Tank[0].speed +     0.06f);
```

it looks horribly like you are trying to add an acceleration (0.06) to your speed while at the same time adding the speed to the position.  The plus sign won't change the speed, it will just calculate the result and use it in the equation.

Do it in two steps:

```
TestName->Tank[0].speed += 0.06f;
TestName->Tank[0].position_y += TankName->Tank[0].speed;
```

When you have that bit working your next issue will be inability to steer.  I think you would be well advised to google vectors (maths, not C++) and the difference between velocity and speed.

Answer (score 1):

Logically,.....Supposing your `defaultspeed` is 1 and `maxspeed` is 2. You probably want another variable, lets call it `deltaSpeed`.

Then your `totalSpeed`(Change in Tank's Position in a direction) is `defaultspeed` * `deltaSpeed`.

You would also need to check if the user is pressing down on the button, if so increase(either by a fixed amount or exponentially) the `deltaSpeed`. When the user release the button then decrease the `deltaSpeed`. This would give the illusion of tank speeding up and slowing down.

Then, when the user presses another direction you could reset the deltaSpeed.

Answer (score 1):

some useful Newtonian equations:

f = ma

v^2 = u^2 + 2as

s = ut + 0.5 * a * t^2

where:

s = distance travelled (m)

u = initial velocity (m/s)

t = time (seconds)

a = acceleration

f = force

m = mass

Rearranging these equations allows you to compute the change in acceleration, and therefore velocity, and therefore distance for a given time period.

Games will model these rules with varying degrees of simplification (e.g. you could code that pressing 'W' will generate a Force of X Newtons in the direction the tank is facing, or you could choose to limit the maximum speed, for make force inversely proportional to current speed (to model for the power equation).

Or you could calculate F as the integral of the power equation over the time period between each simulation pass (which is what a flight sim might do).

Hopefully some ideas to guide you to some useful literature.